# Using fscanf() to input words into a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, scanf

I'm having some issues regarding the use of `fscanf()`. My main objective is to take each word from an input file, and place them sequentially into a 2d array of `char`, like so:

```
Ex:
words[0][] = The
words[1][] = Quick
words[2][] = Brown
words[3][] = Fox
...
```

I've tried some other methods, such as `fgetc()` and placing each character in their spot with nested `for` loops. This seems like overkill when there is obviously more streamlined methods. The way it stands, at each iteration, `wordList` contains the next word to be read. How would I go about assigning the current value of wordList(at each iteration) sequentially into a 2d array?

My current (relevant) code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
FILE *fPtr;
char words[200][50];
char *wordList;

    if (fPtr = fopen(argv[2], "r")) {                          // If the file exists, open it for reading
            while(fscanf(fPtr, "%49s", wordList) == 1) {            // Read in strings from main file into wordList
         // strcpy(words, wordList);
    } else {       
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "ERROR: File could not be opened.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(fPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

The maximum words to be read can safely be assumed to be less than 200. The length of each word can be assumed to be less than 50 characters.

Comment: `while(fscanf(fPtr, "%49s", wordList) == 1) {` --> `int i=0; while(i < 200 && fscanf(fPtr, "%49s", words[i]) == 1) { ++i; }`

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `wordList` to point to.

Comment: As it stands, `wordList` is just an uninitialized pointer. Follow [@BLUEPIXY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242350/using-fscanf-to-input-words-into-a-2d-array#comment73554871_43242350), and comments from the previous question.

Comment: Thank you for all the guidance @BLUEPIXY and those that commented on my previous post. With `words[][]` being a 2d array, i was under the impression they couldn't be assigned using only one dimension. I feel much better about it, thank you everyone!